# disable crawl unwanted subdomain

Tags: web-crawler, subdomain, alexa-internet

How to disable and remove `subdomain.domain.com` being crawled and listed to alexa and other crawlers ? Specially the `cpanel.domain.com` and `webmail.domain.com` that listed into my alexa information page and annoying :/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this article: https://alexa.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200450194-Alexa-s-Web-and-Site-Audit-Crawlers

The Alexa web crawler (robot)  identifies itself as “ia_archiver” in the HTTP “User-agent” header field. The Alexa Internet ia_archiver crawler strictly adheres to robots.txt rules.

To prevent ia_archiver from visiting any part of your site, your robots.txt file should look like this:

```
User-agent: ia_archiver
Disallow: /
```

You can also restrict crawling of specific directories. For example, to prevent ia_archiver from visiting the images directory (and its subdirectories):

```
User-agent: ia_archiver
Disallow: /images/
```

If you can you can place a `robots.txt` in the root of the subdomains you do not wish to have crawled. If these pages are outside of your control; the hosting service should/could have done these or similar restrictions.

Comment: thank you. but i use sharing host and there's no directory named `cpanel` or `webmail`.do i should contact with my hosting service ?

Comment: That's what I would do. It would seem like good practise to disable crawl for those kinds of subdomains. I'm surprised they have not done it. You can check for a `robots.txt` file by going to the url `subdomain.domain.com/robots.txt`.

Comment: `robots.txt`, plural. Contact your hosting service.